# JSFiddle Object Sorting algorithm crash

Tags: javascript

I apologize if it's bit of a stupid question, i'm studying for an JS exam and i took a random assigment that tasks me with sorting JSON data from the URL by year in JSFiddle.
Code goes as in:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gs6eey97/ (i apologize for all the comments).
```

First problem is that console returns sorted list but each sorted element appears twice in the sorted list ([Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CBG5.png)).I thought about adding an if statement just before sorted data is put in the array to filter the duplicates by changing following:

```
minYear.push(minYearPom);
minSort.push(propPom);
```

to the following:

```
if (propPom != minSort[minSort.length - 1]) {
        minYear.push(minYearPom);
        minSort.push(propPom);
      }
```

and Chrome stops responding, i've tried removing

```
minYear.push(minYearPom);
```

as i realized i don't really need it, and Chrome stops responding, i add simple console.log to see values of certain variables to try to figure out what the problem is, and Chrome stops responding.Friend can't seem to find the issue with the code either so if anyone can find the problem i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you get an object with objects,

> ```
> {
>     movies: {
>         tt0111161: {
>             Title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
>             Year: "1994",
>             Runtime: "142",
>             Director: "Frank Darabont",
>             Actors: [
>               "Tim Robbins",
>               "Morgan Freeman",
>               "Bob Gunton",
>               "William Sadler"
>             ],
>             Language: [
>               "English"
>             ],
>             imdbRating: "9.3",
>             imdbVotes: "138"
>         },
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

you need to take the keys, like `tt0111161`, etc. and apply sorting on the array of keys:

```js
var data = { movies: { tt0111161: { Title: "The Shawshank Redemption", Year: "1994", Runtime: "142", Director: "Frank Darabont", Actors: ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"], Language: ["English"], imdbRating: "9.3", imdbVotes: "138" }, tt0068646: { Title: "The Godfather", Year: "1972", Runtime: "175", Director: "Francis Ford Coppola", Actors: ["Marlon Brando", "Al Pacino", "James Caan", "Richard S. Castellano"], Language: ["English", "Italian", "Latin"], imdbRating: "9.2", imdbVotes: "96" } } },
    keys = Object.keys(data.movies);

keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    return data.movies[a].Year - data.movies[b].Year;
});

console.log(keys);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

We use [`Object.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the movies as an array of objects:

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
>   [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
let movies = Object.values(data.movies);

/*
movies = [
    { "Title": "The Shawshank Redemption", ... },
    { "Title": "The Godfather", ... },
    ...
];
*/
```

`currentYear` is used for calculating the age of the films

We then sort the movies with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string Unicode code points.

```
movies.sort((a, b) => a.Year - b.Year);
```

For the average age of the films we use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

```
let avg = movies.reduce((result, currentMovie) => result + (currentYear - currentMovie.Year), 0) / movies.length;
```

Also used in the snippet but not relevant for the sort/average part:

[Arrow function (`... => ...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

[Template literals (`` `...${...}...` ``)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.

```js
let data = { "movies":{ "tt0111161":{ "Title":"The Shawshank Redemption", "Year":"1994", "Runtime":"142", "Director":"Frank Darabont", "Actors":["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman", "Bob Gunton", "William Sadler"], "Language":["English"], "imdbRating":"9.3", "imdbVotes":"138" }, "tt0068646":{ "Title":"The Godfather", "Year":"1972", "Runtime":"175", "Director":"Francis Ford Coppola", "Actors":["Marlon Brando", "Al Pacino", "James Caan", "Richard S. Castellano"], "Language":["English", "Italian", "Latin"], "imdbRating":"9.2", "imdbVotes":"96" }, "tt0071562":{ "Title":"The Godfather: Part II", "Year":"1974", "Runtime":"200", "Director":"Francis Ford Coppola", "Actors":["Al Pacino", "Robert Duvall", "Diane Keaton", "Robert De Niro"], "Language":["English", "Italian", "Spanish", "Latin", "Sicilian"], "imdbRating":"9.1", "imdbVotes":"64" }, "tt0468569":{ "Title":"The Dark Knight", "Year":"2008", "Runtime":"152", "Director":"Christopher Nolan", "Actors":["Christian Bale", "Heath Ledger", "Aaron Eckhart", "Michael Caine"], "Language":["English", "Mandarin"], "imdbRating":"9.0", "imdbVotes":"137" }, "tt0110912":{ "Title":"Pulp Fiction", "Year":"1994", "Runtime":"154", "Director":"Quentin Tarantino", "Actors":["Tim Roth", "Amanda Plummer", "Laura Lovelace", "John Travolta"], "Language":["English", "Spanish", "French"], "imdbRating":"8.9", "imdbVotes":"108" } } }
    movies = Object.values(data.movies),
    currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

movies.sort((a, b) => a.Year - b.Year);
let avg = movies.reduce((result, currentMovie) => {
              return result + (currentYear - currentMovie.Year);
          }, 0) / movies.length;

movies.forEach(movie => console.log(`Title: ${movie.Title} (${movie.Year})`));
console.log(`Average age: ${avg}`);
```